# The complexity of Depth First Search

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Can anyone tell me what's the complexity of Depth First Search?
I have no idea about what does mean by the complexity.

Comment: Time complexity - $O(n)$. Space complexity - $O(n)$.

Comment: The question is about the asymptotic performance of the algorithm. You need to read about 'big O', and the wikipedia article on this subject is a decent place to go. Then, see if you can answer some simpler questions, such as what is the complexity of bubble sort. Finally, tackle DFS!

Answer (score 1):

The *time* complexity of an algorithm is an estimate, how fast it works depending on the size of input data. This [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) talks about the time complexity (there is *space* complexity too - please look yourself).

As for graphs - their size is usually described by two numbers - number of vertices $|V|$ and number of edges $|E|$. So, you need to think about how much total work the DFS algorithm does in terms of these two numbers.